# Will i loose all the ratings and comments i got from previous version app when my new version will be published?

Tags: android, google-play

i have updated my app and republished it with version name=2 and version code=1.0.1.Now its written in developer console that version 1.0 unpublished and version 1.0.1 in production.Will i loose all the ratings and comments i got from previous version when my new version will be published?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: no your comments and rating will be still dr ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your comments and rating will still there, but comments will be flagged with the version which was been published.

Comment: I just made a small update to my app in new version

Comment: no worries, update as much as you need, that's the play store idea, keep your app up to date.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't loose anything. What happens is that these comments get a mark, that they were written for an older version.

Comment: I just made a small update to my app in newer version